# How to handle exceptions from a published event in Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception

My application makes use of Spring events

```
@Resource
ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

publisher.publishEvent(myEvent);

...

@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
public void handleEvent(MyEvent myEvent)
```

There are a lot of these events. Is there a way to deal with potential exceptions that come from these subscribe methods?

Ideally in a similar way to how Exceptions can be handled in Web MVC for RequestMapping requests, i.e.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd likely use an [`ApplicationEventMulticaster`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationEventMulticaster.html) in this scenario, specifically the [`SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.html). The `ApplicationEventMulticaster` is really just a more heavily featured version of the `Publisher` and allows you to do things like, for example, publish asynchronously.

However, the feature that you're looking for here is the [`#setErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.html#setErrorHandler-org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler-) method on the `Multicaster`, where you can set a standard Spring [`ErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ErrorHandler.html), or (likely what you want to do), roll your own over the `ErrorHandler` interface.